# Parent dying overseas - visit now or attend funeral?

Tags: travel, priorities, funeral-burial-levaya, choleh-sick, kibbud-av-veim-honoring

A person lives far away from a dying parent and cannot afford more than one visit. What do the halachic sources say about when they should visit? Should they visit the parent immediately and miss the funeral, or is it more important to attend the funeral in person (and say Kaddish at the graveside in the case of a son)?

Comment: I feel like this is very case specific. Are there other children? Other children who would say Kaddish? Is their parent awake/alert/sentient? When is the last time the child saw the parent? Is the other parent alive and does s/he have a preference?

Comment: I don't know what the sources say, but I know which I'd prefer if I was the parent.

Comment: @DoubleAA If those other facts influence the answer then they should be included in the answer.

Comment: @DoubleAA, it seems reasonable to expect that the sources would address the general question of comparing the value of honoring ones parents while they're alive and after they've passed away, or the general question of prioritizing visiting the sick vs. honoring the deceased.